# Can not display the features using JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have tried to display the features such as textfield, buttons when using the JFrame library but when I run the program from the main class, the window pops up without anything on it.

```
package Demo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
public class Display extends JFrame{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textfield;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;

    private int width,height;
    private String title;

    public Display(String title,int width, int height) {        
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        createDisplay();

    }

    public void createDisplay() {

        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        textfield = new JTextField("Hello everyone, I'm learning java",10);
        frame.add(textfield);

        button1 = new JButton("Bold");
        frame.add(button1);
        button2 = new JButton("Italic");    
        frame.add(button2);

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) `frame.setVisible(true);` This should be last, after `frame.pack();` 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I have tried to corrected like the other posts, but It does not work. When I run the program, only the last button which is button 2 appears on the screen

Comment: `only the last button which is button 2 appears on the screen`  - only a single component can be added to the `CENTER` of the `BorderLayout`. Use an appropriate layout manager. See the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples. Keep a link to the tutorial handy for examples of all Swing basics.